# python ftplibでファイルをダウンロードしてくるCSVファイルのファイル名を正規表現で検索&ダウンロードしたい！

Tags: python3, windows, ftp

#### 前提・実現したいこと

python ftplibでCSVファイルをダウンロードしたいです。その際、ファイル名の日付部分が日々変わるので、正規表現で検索してダウンロードしてきたいと思います。
しかし、以下エラーがでるので解決方法を教えてください。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
TypeError: findall() missing 1 required positional argument: 'string'
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
import ftplib
from logging import getLogger, StreamHandler, Formatter, DEBUG
import re

## FTP情報
HOST = '***.ne.jp'
PORT = 21
USER = '***'
PASSWORD = '***'
DIRECTORY = '/***/***'
## 取得するファイル名の生成

FILE_NAME = (re.findall('item2019????????-?.csv')) #←ここを正規表現で検索したい！
print(FILE_NAME)
```

#### 試したこと

reでFILE_NAME = (re.findall('item2019????????-?.csv')) としたのですが、str型にするのにどうしたらいいのかわかりませんでした。

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.7.3
Windows7
jupyter notebook

Answer (score 1):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html?highlight=findall#re.findall)は引数として`検索パターン`と`検索対象文字列`の最低2つが必要です。
質問のコードは引数に検索パターンのみが指定されているためエラーとなっています。

下記のサンプルコードは[`ftp.nlst`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst)を使ってシンプルなファイル一覧を取得して、正規表現で該当するファイル名を探すコードの抜粋例です。
ここでは[`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html?highlight=match#re.match)を使っていますが、マッチング方法や戻り値が違うだけで引数は`re.findall`と同様です。

```
import re

# items = ftp.nlst(".") # ファイル一覧が配列で返る
items = [ 'item201912301913-1.csv', 'item201912301913-1.xlsx', 'item2019[8文字ならOK-！.csv', 'readme.txt' ] # 正規表現用サンプルコード
for item in items:
    if re.match(r'item2019.{8}-.\.csv', item):
        print(item)
```